# Why reported the path does not exist when automatically generating time series in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: path, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now using Apache IoTDB Version 0.13 to automatically generate time series. However IoTDB still report that the path does not exist when writing data? I already set data to existing paths when setting automatic writing process, so why this problem still happens?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.